# IMO 1988, problem 6

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, square-numbers, vieta-jumping

In 1988, IMO presented a problem, to prove that $k$ must be a square if $a^2+b^2=k(1+ab)$, for positive integers $a$, $b$ and $k$.
I am wondering about the solutions, not obvious from the proof.  Beside the trivial solutions a or $b=0$ or 1 with $k=0$ or $1$, an obvious solution is $a=b^3$ so that the equation becomes $b^6+b^2=b^2(1+b^4)$ . Are there any other solutions?

Comment: There are some very detailed analyses of this problem here searchable with the words 'IMO 1988'.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/250172/when-is-fa-b-fraca2b21ab-a-perfect-square-rational-number/250187#250187

Answer (score 18):

This is a famous problem, here is one of the solutions that I like the most that I read it in a book previously, but later in a topic on here I realized the importance of the problem (The credit goes to T. Andreescu & R. Gelca If I remember it correctly, but I'm not sure, since 11 individuals in that year solved this problem and I'm not sure about their solutions):

Solution: Suppose that $\displaystyle \frac{a^2+b^2}{a.b+1}=x$ We want to prove that for every non-negative integer pairs $(\alpha,\beta)$ with the property that $\displaystyle \frac{\alpha^2+\beta^2}{\alpha\beta+1}=x$ and $\alpha \geq \beta$ the pair that minimizes $\alpha+\beta$ must imply $\beta=0$. If that happened, then $x=\alpha^2$.
So, suppose that $(\alpha,\beta)$ is such a pair that minimizes $\alpha+\beta$ but $\beta>0$. then we can obtain the equation $y^2 - \beta xy + \beta^2 -x =0$ from $\displaystyle \frac{y^2+\beta^2}{y\beta+1}=x$. This equation has $\alpha$ as one of its roots and since the sum of the roots is $\beta x$, the other root must be $\beta x - \alpha$. Now if we prove that $0 \leq \beta x - \alpha < \alpha$ then we're done because this contradicts the minimality of $(\alpha,\beta)$

$x = \displaystyle \frac{\alpha^2+\beta^2}{\alpha\beta+1}<\frac{2\alpha^2}{\alpha \beta} = \frac{2 \alpha}{\beta} \implies \beta x-\alpha < \alpha$

and it's also possible to show that $\beta.x - \alpha \geq 0$ but honestly I don't remember that part of the proof and I leave it to you. That completes the proof.

(Also check that wikipedia link provided by pre-kidney).

Comment: The question does not ask for a proof, it asks for the listing of the solutions of the equation in $k$, $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 10):

The technique for this type of problem is called "Vieta root jumping". On the wikipedia page describing this technique, this very problem is used as an example. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta_jumping#Example).

Of course there are many more solutions; we can enumerate them by flipping repeatedly and using symmetry. For example, your solution $(b, b^3)$ is the result of flipping $(b,0)$ when $k=b^2$. But if we flip around $b^3$ instead, we get the new solution $(b^5-b, b^3)$.

Indeed, $$x^2-b^5x+(b^6-b^2)=(x-b)(x-b^5+b)$$
so we also have $$b^6 + (b^5-b)^2 = b^2(1 + b^3(b^5-b))$$

Answer (score 5):

All solutions can be written as:
$$
\text{if $n$ is even:}\enspace a_n= { \sum\limits_{i=0}^{{n\over{2}}} {(-1)^{i+{n\over{2}}}{{n\over{2}}+i\choose {n\over{2}}-i}g^{4i+1}}} \\
\text{if $n$ is odd:}\enspace a_n= \sum\limits_{i=0}^{{n-1\over{2}}} (-1)^{i+{n-1\over{2}}}{1+{n-1\over{2}}+i \choose {n-1\over{2}}-i}g^{4i+3} \implies \\
{{a_n}^2+{a_{n+1}}^2\over{a_na_{n+1}+1}}=g^2\\
$$
Or also:
$$
a_n={g{\bigg({g^2+\sqrt{g^4-4}\over{2}}\bigg)}^n\over{\sqrt{g^4-4}}}  - {g{\bigg({g^2-\sqrt{g^4-4}\over{2}} \bigg)}^n\over{\sqrt{g^4-4}}} \\
$$

[see here for complete solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1897942/international-mathematical-olympiad-1988-problem-6-canonical-solution/1909572#1909572)

Answer (score 4):

Not quite a proof to the original IMO problem, but there definately is a very easy way to compute **all** possible answers.
Also it demonstrates that here, Vieta jumping is basically just using
symmetry to jump between the two solutions of the good old quadratic formula.

Nothing complicated below, but I haven't seen this explanation anywhere else.

Suppose:
$$
{{a^2+b^2} \over {1+ab}} = c
$$
Then using the quadratic formula to solve b (and a little rewriting) gives:
$$
b = {ac \pm \sqrt {a^2 (c^2-4) + 4c} \over 2}
$$
Using this we can compute all answers for any given c. 
Eg: assume c = 4. Then we get:
$$
b = {a \cdot 4 \pm \sqrt {a^2 \cdot 12 + 16} \over 2}
$$
We know that a = 0 will always provide a solution. That gives us:
$$
a = 0 \Rightarrow b = {{0 \cdot 4\pm \sqrt {0 \cdot 12 + 16}} \over 2} = 2 \Rightarrow (a,b) = (0,2) 
$$
But because of the symmetry, if (0,2) is a solution, then (2,0) must
also be a solution. And since the quadratic formula has 2 solutions,
it will produce another solution.
$$
a = 2 \Rightarrow \space b = {{2 \cdot 4 \pm \sqrt {4 \cdot 12 + 16}} \over 2} = 0 \space or \space 8 \Rightarrow (a,b) = (2,8)
$$
$$
a = 8 \Rightarrow \space b = {{8 \cdot 4 \pm \sqrt {64 \cdot 12 + 16}} \over 2} = {32 \pm 28\over 2} = 2 \space or \space 30 \Rightarrow (a,b) = (8,30)
$$
$$
a = 30 \Rightarrow \space b = {{30 \cdot 4 \pm \sqrt {900 \cdot 12 + 16}} \over 2} = {120 \pm 104\over 2} = 8 \space or \space 112 \Rightarrow (a,b) = (30,112)
$$
Same can be done for c = 9, 16, 25, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Supposing that

$$ \frac{a^2 + b^2}{ab + 1} = k$$ then

$$ a^2 - a(kb) + (b^2 - k) = 0 $$

So using quadratic formula gives: $$ a = \frac{kb \pm \sqrt{k^2b^2 -4(b^2 -k)}}{2}$$

The solutions are when $k = b^2 $ and thus $a= kb = b^3$

So $$ b = 1 , a = 1 , k= 1$$
$$b = 2 , a = 8, k = 4$$

$$ b= 3, a= 27, k = 9 $$ and so on....

There are other ways of getting more solutions than these such as b = 8, a = 30 and k = 4 where k is not $b^2$ or $a = b^3$ and of course the zero one. I have not yet found a way to find more solutions than this.

Comment: But what about for example $b=8,a=30,k=4$ ? Clearly we don't have : $ k=b^2$ or $a=b^3$. But nevertheless we have :  $ \enspace \frac{8^2+30^2}{8.30+1}=4$..

Comment: Oh yes, you are right. Thank you for that, I will look into this question more and will edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let the following sequence of polynomials
\begin{equation*}
P_1(n)\,=\,n\,,\,\, P_2(n)\,=\,n^3,\ldots,
P_{k+2}(n)\,=\,\frac{P^2_{k+1}(n)-n^2}{P_k(n)}, \,\,\,k\in\mathbb N,
\end{equation*}
which in fact have the following general formula
\begin{equation}
P_m(n)\,=\,\sum_{r=0}^{\left[\frac{m-1}{2}\right]}
(-1)^r\,\left(
\begin{array}{c} 
\!m\!-\!r\!-\!1\! \\ r
\end{array}
\right)
\,n^{2m-4r-1}.
\label{polunomial}
\end{equation}
Then one can show the following: *If $a,b$ are positive integers with $b\ge a$, such that
$$
\frac{a^2+b^2}{1+ab}=k
$$
is also an integer, then $k$ is a perfect square, i.e., $k=n^2$, and there exists an $m\in\mathbb N$, such that*
$$
a=P_m(n)\quad\text{and}\quad b=P_{m+1}(n).
$$

Answer (score 0):

For given positive integers a and b, and applying simple division of $(a^2 + b^2)$ by $(ab + 1)$ we have quotient as a/b and remainder as $(b^2 - a/b)$.

For the result to be a perfect division, the remainder must be zero. Therefore $(b^2 - a/b) = 0$ which gives the relation $a=b^3$.

Applying $a=b^3$ in the equation $x=(a^2 + b^2)/(ab + 1)$, we have $x=b^2$ which is a perfect square of an integer.

All the number pairs $(a,b)$ of the form $(b^3,b)$ are solutions of the above equation and the number which is a perfect square is of the form $x = b^2$ applicable for all $b$ belonging to a set of positive integers.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).