# Simple solution to Question 6 from the 1988 Math Olympiad

Tags: contest-math

**Recall Question 6 of the 1988 Math Olympiad**

Question 6 is as follows:

> Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers such that $ab + 1$ divides $a^2 +
>  b^2$. Show that $$\frac{a^2+b^2}{ab+1}$$ is the square of an integer.

My proof:

> Proof:
>
> Let us denote the square of an integer by $k^2$. We have to show that
>   $$\frac{a^2+b^2}{ab+1}=k^2$$ for some $a > 0$ and $b > 0$ where $a, b,
> > k \in \Bbb Z$.
>
> Rewriting the equation:
>
> $$a^2+b^2=k^2(ab+1)=k^2ab+k^2$$
>
> Let $k = b$:
>
> $$a^2+b^2=b^3a+b^2 \Rightarrow a^2=b^3a \Rightarrow a=b^3$$
>
> To check, let's substitute these relations back in the original
>   expression:
>
> $$\frac{a^2+b^2}{ab+1}=\frac{(k^3)^2+(k)^2}{(k^3)(k)+1}=\frac{k^6+k^2}{k^4+1}=\frac{k^2(k^4+1)}{k^4+1}=k^2$$

Two of things I would like to know about this Olympiad Question:

1. Is this proof correct?
2. Is there a reliable way to check if a certain solution to a proof already exist?

**Background**

Every now and then I visit Youtube for educational purposes. I've been a great fan of Kurzgesagt, Numberphile, Computerphile, and other educational channels. For anyone not having heard of these channels I would greatly recommended to check them out!

Today I was watching this video on the channel of Numberphile: [The World's Best Mathematician (*) - Numberphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MXJ-zpJeY3E). In this video a great mathematician Professor Tao tells about his passion for mathematics from a young age. At some point in this video it is mentioned that Tao only scored 1 out of 7 points for the infamous Question 6 from the 1988 Math Olympiad. In the next couple of frames this video shows the details of the question. At that moment I paused the video to try and solve this question by myself, with only pen and paper.

After 10 minutes or so I figured out the solution to this problem and questioned myself why the question is called *infamous*. I came across some solutions at this site that are, in my opinion, mindblowing in terms of length and mathematical notation, for example [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1897942/international-mathematical-olympiad-1988-problem-6-canonical-solution/1909572#1909572) solution. Then I read something about Vieta-jumping that I'm not familiar with and how it's used to solve this question (or not). A rather simple solution I came across is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1820078/imo-1988-question-no-6-possible-values-of-a-and-b-displaystyle-fraca2/1833768#1833768) one. I think the elegance and quality of a solution is greatly influenced by its length and level of simplicity in terms of notation, terminology, and construction.

As far as I did my silly online research I couldn't find a solution that was equivalent to mine. Therefore I thought it would be a good idea to share it and let other people, with a much broader understandig of existing mathematical proofs, decide if this proof is correct (and a known solution).

Comment: I mentioned that thread in my post. First, it is not a duplicate, since my question differs a lot from that one. Second, the solution mentioned in that thread also differs from my solution.

Comment: Its always best to get quickly to your question, and then give us details about how you found it. The question is what volunteers can help you with, not your biography, and if people want to figure out quickly if they can help you with the question. Remember: You are asking people to give you their time, don't request more of it than you need.

Comment: `Let k=b ⇒ a=b^3` You can't assume that $k=b\,$, or that $a=b^3\,$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I understand. I will reformat this question.

Comment: @dxiv Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Pascal In your proof, haven't you started by assuming the result?

Comment: If $k=b$, then your answer is correct. But you haven't proven that $k=b$ is the only possible solution, only that $a^3=b$ is one possible answer.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews How do you proof other solutions exist?

Comment: It's not up to me to prove other solutions exist, it is up to you to prove they don't if you are saying this is a proof. It's possible these are the only solutions, but you don't know that.

Comment: @Pascal You assumed that $k=b$ without any reason or justification. This reduced the problem from *arbitrary* integers $a,b$ to the much smaller subset of integers $a,b$ with $a=b^3$. It's (almost) as if I said "*look, let's just assume $a=b=1\,$, and in that case the fraction is $1$ i.e. a perfect square QED*". That's not a proof, and doesn't answer the original question.

Comment: You have shown that *if* $a=b^3$, then $\frac{a^2+b^2}{ab+1}$ is a square. But you have to show that for *any* $a$ and $b$: if $ab+1$ divides $a^2+b^2$, then it is a square. It's like 'proving' that 'if $ab$ is a whole number, then $ab$ is a square' by saying 'well, if $a=b$ then $ab$ is a square'.

Comment: @dxiv I took $k=b$ because that would allow me to eliminate the terms $b^2$ on both sides of the equation.

Comment: @Pascal And I took $a=b=1$ because that gave me a square right away. Think at why my "proof" isn't valid, then you'll realize why yours isn't, either. You can't simply postulate that $k=b$ just because it simplifies your calculations.

Comment: @Bram28 That makes sense to me. I'm going to try and fix my proof.

Comment: $a=8,b=30$ is a solution, for example, with $k=2$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$a=8,b=30$ gives $k=2$. So you haven't gotten all answers when you've assumed $k=b$.

You are trying to prove it for all cases. You've only proven it for some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Dividing by the first principle
$$
ab+1)a^2+b^2(\frac{a}{b}
$$
$$
\ \ \ \ \ \ a^2+\frac{a}{b}
$$

---

$$
\ \ \ \ \ \ b^2-\frac{a}{b}
$$
Since ab+1 completely divides $$a^2+b^2$$
$$b^2-\frac{a}{b}=0\\
\therefore a=b^3
$$
The quotient is $$ a\over{b}$$
Putting the value of a
$$\frac{a}{b}=b^2$$
Hence it is a perfect square

Comment: Check out the first paragraph, please. I don't have a clue as to what you are doing there. Also, the solution $a=30, b=8$ proves that your claim $a=b^3$ is simply false.