# Two different polynomial expressions for certain primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, computational-mathematics, conjectures

Here is an other random conjecture which I have no clue how to prove:

$a,b\in\mathbb N^+\wedge a^2+b^2+ab\in\mathbb P\implies\exists$
$A,B\in\mathbb N^+:A^2+B^2-AB=a^2+b^2+ab$.

Tested for $a,b<20,000$ on my 32 bit tabloid.

I would like to see a proof or an counter-example.

Comment: Did you notice any patterns? What happens if you put $A=a, B=a+b$

Comment: What does it matter that it's prime?

Comment: @Randall: I must have done something wrong, because it seemed only work for primes.

Comment: @Mark The "pattern" has to do with reflections on conics - see my answer. This is closely related to [Vieta jumping and similar topics.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1898116/242)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(a+b)^2-(a+b)b+b^2=a^2+ab+b^2.$$

Comment: Better to bring the innate symmetry to the fore rather than pull the answer out of a hat - see my answer (and see [reflections on conics and Vieta  jumping.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1898116/242)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $ $ If $\,x_1=a\,$ is a root of $\,f(x)\ =\ x^2+\,\color{#c00}b\,x+b^2\,$ then so too is $\,\overbrace{x_2 = -\color{#c00}b-x_1}^{\large {\rm root\ sum}\ =\ -\color{#c00}b} = -b-a$

So $\,-x_2 = a\!+\!b\,$ is a root of $\,f(-x) = x^2-b\,x+b^2$