# Solutions in $\mathbb{Z}$ for $x + y = xy$ : Proof by infinite descent

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, infinite-descent

I need to prove that there exist no solutions apart from $(0,0)$ and $(2,2)$ through infinite descent. I understand the premise of descent, and was even able to solve another similar question. A small hint would be appreciated, as this presently has me stumped and I just can't figure it out.
I've tried taking $x = 2x_1, y = 2y_1$, but to no avail as I seemingly can't get back the original equation by doing so. Is there a flaw in this logic?

Comment: Hint: for larger integers $x+y<2\max(x,y)$.

Comment: I understand it's part of the question, but infinite descent is really overkill. If $b$ divides $x$ but not $y$ (or $y$ but not $x$) we immediately find a contradiction, so $x=y$. Then $2x=x^{2}$ which is trivially solved.

Comment: Hint for other cases:  Both negative obviously false,  one positive one negative,  $|x+y|<|x|+|y|\leq 2 \max(|x|,|y|)$

Comment: @Andijvie: all we can deduce from your argument by contradiction is that $x=\pm y$. I realise that $x=-y$ is easy to rule out, but you should at least mention it.

Comment: @QC_QAOA, could you please elaborate on the hint? I'm unsure as to how to use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\rm\color{#c00}{Descent}$ is via $\rm\color{#0a0}{reflection}$ symmetry on hyperbola $\,\cal C\!: x+y = xy,\,$ i.e. $(x,y)$ on $\cal C\Rightarrow \color{#0a0}{(y,x)}$ on $\cal C$. Thus if $\,(a,b)\in\Bbb N$ and $(a,b)$ on $\,{\cal C}\,\ \color{#90f}{{\rm has}\ a> 2}$ then $\,\color{#c00}{b < a}\,$ so its reflection $\color{#0a0}{(b,a)}$ has $\rm\color{#c00}{smaller}$ $x$ coordinate. We can repeat this descent step again on $(b,a)$  and again $\,\ldots$ (i.e. **infinite descent**) since $\color{#90f}{{\rm also}\ b > 2}$ (else we get contradictions: $\,b\!=\!2\Rightarrow a\!=\!2;\ $ $b\!=\!1\Rightarrow a\!+\!1 = a;\ $ $b\!=\!0\Rightarrow a\!=\!0)$.

**Remark** $ $ Generally (reflection) symmetries govern descent on integer points on conics - see the links I give [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1898116/242) in the context of less trivial **Vieta jumping** reflection symmetry.

[image]

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #000]{\text{the hyperbola}\,\ x+y = xy}$$

Comment: There are of course quicker ways to deduce contradictions from the hypothesis that there is an integer point $(a,b)$ with $a > 2$ (e.g. using the stronger $a>2\Rightarrow \color{#c00}{b < 2})$ but the point of the above is to show how it can be viewed as a special case of general descent methods for conics.

Comment: this is really beautiful and eye-opening. thanks a lot for this post. i wish i could verify two solutions.

Answer (score 3):

One should always have a feel of the problem. In this case, the finiteness of solutions is not due to number-theoretic properties (e.g. $4m=2n+1$ has no solutions for number-theoretic properties), but because of **size**. Adding two numbers is generally much smaller than multiplying them. So the solutions will be confined to small numbers.

To make this precise, rewrite the equation when both $x$ and $y$ are non-zero: $$\frac1x+\frac1y=1$$
This is much clearer, for if two numbers are to add up to one, at least one is greater than or equal to 1/2. This means at least one of the number is either 1 or 2. This gives all the solutions.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Your answer is fine, but how do I show descent in this case?

Comment: @asdf256 There is no descent here. By the way in my opinion this answer is more natural than infinite descent.

Answer (score 1):

Write: $y = x(y-1)$. This shows $x \mid y$. Thus let $y = kx, k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Substitute $kx$ back into the equation for $y$: $kx = x(kx-1) = kx^2-x$. Observe that $x = 0$ is a solution and thus $y = 0$ as well in the original equation. So $(0,0)$ is a solution. Besides this, for $x \neq 0$, $k = kx-1\implies 1 = k(x-1)\implies k \mid 1\implies k =\pm 1$. If $k = 1 \implies y = x \implies 2x = x^2\implies x(x-2) = 0 \implies x = 0,2$. Thus another solution is $(2,2)$. If $k = -1 \implies x = -y \implies xy = x+y = 0 \implies x = 0$ or $y=0$. Either one gets back to $(0,0)$ being a solution and this is already accounted for. So there are $2$ solutions: $(0,0), (2,2)$.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how this particular solution is in the "spirit" of infinite descent, it seems like just algebra to me; I've done something similiar to derive my solution, but I don't get how I would prove it using **descent**

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Infinite Descent solution: Observe that $x$ must be even. For if $x$ were odd, then if $y$ is odd, then $x+y$ is even while $xy$ is odd. Thus there is no solution. If $y$ is even, then $x+y$ is odd and $xy$ is even. Thus there is no solution either. Now with $x$ being even, then $y = x(y-1)$ is also even. Thus we might let $x = 2x_1, y = 2y_1$ where $x_1,y_1 \in \mathbb{Z}$. Substituting $2x_1,2y_1$ for $x,y$ respectively into the equation, we have: $2x_1+2y_1 = 4x_1y_1\implies x_1+y_1 = 2x_1y_1$. Observe that if $x_1$ or $y_1$ is odd, then both are odd. We have: $2 = \dfrac{x_1+y_1}{x_1y_1}= \dfrac{1}{x_1}+\dfrac{1}{y_1}\le 1+1 = 2$. Thus equality occurs when $x_1 = y_1 = 1$. This gives $x = y = 2$. So if either is even then both are even. Thus again we have: $x_1 = 2x_2, y_1 = 2y_2$, and substituting this into the new equation: $2x_2+2y_2 = 4x_2y_2 \implies x_2+y_2 = 2x_2y_2$. Observe at this point that $x_2,y_2$ must be both even. For if one is odd, then the other is odd too and for this we already processed it and have that $x_2 = y_2 = 1$ if they are both odd, hence $x_1 = 2 = y_1$. But this can't occur since it violates the equation: $x_1+y_1 = 2x_1y_1$ above. Thus we have that $x_2,y_2$ are both even, and we can repeat this process indefinitely which yields a contradiction because it must stop at some point. In brief, we have again $2$ solutions: $(x,y) = (0,0), (2,2)$.

Comment: Ah, that makes so much more sense. Thanks a lot.