# An alternate motivation 1988 IMO question #6 (the infamous one)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, proof-explanation, contest-math, square-numbers

This is an especially famous problem that you can check out an alternative asking and full solutions to [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/483771/imo-1988-problem-6) and, more formally, [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/1988_IMO_Problems/Problem_6). This post is not asking for solutions or full fledged proofs; rather, I am wondering whether an alternative motivation that I've thought of would be correct (if I were to write it out full-fledgedly and completely).

The problem asks:

> Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers such that $ab + 1$ divides $a^2 + b^2$. Show that $$\frac{a^2 + b^2}{ab + 1}$$
>   is the square of an integer

My idea/motivation stems from the fact that a square of a number can only be $0$ or $1$ in mod(3). That means that $a^2 + b^2$ can equal either $0, 1$, or $2$ mod(3). If either $a$ or $b$ or both are equivalent to $0$ mod(3), that means that $ab + 1$ is 1, and the overall fraction becomes $0$ mod(3), which is a square of an integer. If $a$ and $b$ are both $1$, then that means that $\frac{a^2 + b^2}{ab + 1} = \frac{1^2 + 1^2}{1 \cdot 1 + 1} = 1$ in mod(3). Thus all cases are accounted for, and so the fraction in question is a perfect square.

Am I missing something (other than a formal proof)? Once again, my question differs from others in the idea as well as the topic that I am inquiring about. Thanks to all the people who help.

Comment: So it's a square modulo $3$. I suppose that's a start. Are there any numbers $\ne 3$ for which it's a square modulo?

Comment: $3 \equiv 0 (\text{mod }3)$, but 3 is not a square of integers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a logical flaw, we must have $\forall x \in \mathbb{Z} \implies  x^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$ or $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$.

It doesn't mean that number that have remainder $0$ or $1$ are squares.

For example, any multiple of $3$ is congruent to $0$ $\pmod{3}$, but only some of them are squares.